# Java submit button action

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, submit

im training with GUI in Java. So I started creating pet game prototype or smth similar like game.
I have created menu to choose what to do, `Register`, `Info`, or `Exit` aplication.
Created fields and dorpdownBox to choose  everything for register.
Also made `sumbit` button(its very start so i added just max characters validation on petName). 
Now im stucked, i dont know how to take all information from dropdownBox and textbox that has been chosen and sent to other `class Pet`. I have googled but havent found anything that would be clear.

Maybe someone could give me some tips or write part for my code.
I want to take selected `PetName` , `PetType`, `PetGender` to other `class pet`.

P.s. i have copied many lines from google so I understand only 80-90% my code.

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main (String []args){
        new Main("Meniu"); // Create title

    }
// Main class constructor
    public Main(String title) {
        super(title); 
        setMenu(); //create menu
        setSize(300, 400);// size
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // close running program if window are closed
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // set window position at center
        setResizable(false); //resizable or not
        show();
    }// Main class constructor

// menu choices
    JMenuItem Registration, Apie, Exit;

// menu method for creation and style   
    private void setMenu() {
        JMenuBar barObj = new JMenuBar(); // create menuBar obj
        JMenu messagesObj = new JMenu("Meniu"); //create menu bar menu object

        barObj.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); // set menu bar bg color

        Registration = new JMenuItem("Registration"); 
        Registration.setToolTipText("Push to register"); // write text when u hang mouse over
        Registration.addActionListener(this);   
        Registration.setBackground(Color.WHITE); // set menu bar menu options bg color
        messagesObj.add(Registration); // add Registration into messages

        Apie = new JMenuItem("Apie");
        Apie.setToolTipText("Push for information");
        Apie.addActionListener(this);
        Apie.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        messagesObj.add(Apie);  

        Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        Exit.setToolTipText("Here you will exit");
        Exit.addActionListener(this);
        Exit.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        messagesObj.add(Exit);



        barObj.add(messagesObj);
        setJMenuBar(barObj);
    } //create menu end


// implemented method
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == Registration){
            int registReply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Norite registruotis?", 
                "Išeiti", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(registReply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ //registReply is what u have choosen
                petRegistration ();
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == Apie)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Jus esate informacijos lange.", "Apie", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);                    
        else if (e.getSource() == Exit){
            int exitReply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Ar norite Exit?", 
                    "Išeiti", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);// exitReply is what u have choosen
                if(exitReply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){// if its has been chose/ program will shutdown
                    System.exit(0);
                }           
        } // if end
    }// actionPerformed

    public void petRegistration(){

        Container container = getContentPane();
// petName textbox and label        
        JTextField jtfRegLabel = new JTextField("***Registration***", 25);
        jtfRegLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        jtfRegLabel.setEditable(false);


        JTextField jtfText1 = new JTextField(7);
        JTextField jtfNameLabel = new JTextField("Pet Name (min 3, max 16 letters)", 17);
        jtfNameLabel.setEditable(false);
        jtfText1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(16)); // add limit to text box

// pettype combobox and label
        Frame frame = new Frame("Choice");
        Label label = new Label("What is your Choice:");
        Choice choice = new Choice();

        frame.add(choice);
        choice.add("Cat        ");
        choice.add("Dog        ");
        choice.add("Fish       ");
        choice.add("Mouse      ");
        choice.add("Bird       ");
        choice.add("Horse      ");

        JTextField jtfTypeLabel = new JTextField("Pet Type, Choose one ", 17);
        jtfTypeLabel.setEditable(false);

// petGender combobox and label

        Choice choice1 = new Choice();
        frame.add(choice1);
        choice1.add("Male       ");
        choice1.add("Female     ");

        JTextField jtfGenderLabel = new JTextField("Pet Gender, Choose one ", 17);
        jtfGenderLabel.setEditable(false);

// submit registration  
        JButton submitRegObj = new JButton("Submit");



        container.add(jtfRegLabel);
        container.add(jtfText1);
        container.add(jtfNameLabel);
        container.add(choice);
        container.add(jtfTypeLabel);
        container.add(choice1);
        container.add(jtfGenderLabel);
        container.add(submitRegObj);    

        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300, 400); // set size of window
        setVisible(true);// set it visible


    }

}// Main clases end
```

Pet.java

```
public class Pet {
    private String petName;
    private String petType;
    private String petGender;

    public Pet(String petName, String petType, String petGender) {
        super();
        this.petName = petName;
        this.petType = petType;
        this.petGender = petGender;
    }


}
```

I think JTextFieldLimit  class is necessary. Its just make max characters validation.

Thanks.

Comment: A couple things...1. What is the problem? 2. You should start off with something much smaller. This code is REALLY bad form. I would suggest that instead of copying and pasting from google, you learn to write it yourself.

Comment: show class `Choice` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are mixing frameworks.  Swing and AWT components don't play well together.  I'd highly recommend against using AWT components and stick to the Swing framework.

Secondly, don't use `JTextField`s for labels, that's what `JLabel` is for

Start by taking the fields that are used for registriation and add them to their own `JPanel` as class instance fields...

```
public class RegistrationPanel extends JPanel {

    JTextField jtfName;
    JComboBox cbType;
    JComboBox cbSex;

    // Constructor and other code //
}
```

Then, in your `RegistrationPanel`, provide appropriate setters and getters...

```
public String getPetName() {
    return jtfName.getText();
}

public void setPetName(String name) {
    jtfName.setText(name);
}

// Other setters and getters //
```

This way, when you need it, you can retrieve the values from the panel.

When the user selects the registration menu, you would create a new instance of this panel and add it to your frame.  You could even make use of a `CardLayout` to help switch between views

To make life easier, use `enum` types for restricted values like type and sex.

I highly recommend that you take the time to read through

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)